# (iOS react-native) Contents overlay status bar after Vimeo video goes fullscreen in react-native-webview

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, react-navigation, fullscreen

I'm using react-native-webview to implement Vimeo videos.

Normally, [the header is right under the status bar](https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/72460525_760243127755058_1602742766775828480_n.png?_nc_cat=107&_nc_eui2=AeHlOhyvAamEhRGRl1wIDZd9xYa73qmLl9OrsY_8LVFlHs2S0DX9njV2v8cwbDKe7H4DZ7purpXnh5NR-80_Kcv7_q0gDotRlg4MGME1vr0bWg&_nc_oc=AQkfdMj030MKV7aBe3dg-ee9mVpM0bYgK1QjKkC2Ub6_6VqN588qHKO50kJDkjb1cBc&_nc_ht=scontent-hkg3-1.xx&oh=c912640926b6d71c7fd0bddbfa91db7c&oe=5E200113)

When I click play button, the WebView goes fullscreen, this is normal.
While the video is playing in fullscreen mode, I rotate the device twice (from portrait to landscape and then back to portrait) and then quit fullscreen mode. The header now overlays the status bar, not only in current screen but all screens.

[Fullscreen portrait](https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/74531730_651197558740205_9192075619486138368_n.png?_nc_cat=107&_nc_eui2=AeGQLEyH9MlxorXW7QLvP79kqm3xmi-fv_HpT0lfsIe6xEVdzLVfuYcvE5uSk3rLRjrxTgQ5FeIABFVKu7ZaBpBvITrVCpN2YBe_tiwJrlnQeg&_nc_oc=AQlQyADJcVCnYspr9xi6cS5n80KyT9EqMpYAPiZWF-6MUA7VDzspUJ1njx508t9J-JE&_nc_ht=scontent-hkg3-1.xx&oh=52f7dc9a960da9240aab13ec69944ed9&oe=5E1C9DC6), [Fullscreen landscape](https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/72556184_520715545373876_1456484291235020800_n.png?_nc_cat=104&_nc_eui2=AeEqRFSliPmAlHco1UtdaLAF8dxmSn3RCknmiGFo1cL0o7scGL9xDWDTVd0GjB4vJb3wZA-5MFkPT_U_Jjf_7xKskwDxUauFsDBjAtlNaF5sQQ&_nc_oc=AQmZ9iyKC_D40ojz__3RskpsidKgTCzhuVoQ6NeGSjc1bhAK-izz1dWT-SO3e0yh0F4&_nc_ht=scontent-hkg3-1.xx&oh=21d3a3ead6a9f045742941b447c9bf05&oe=5E1C694D), [Back to portrait](https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/72564800_457488928186434_6967186614883713024_n.png?_nc_cat=106&_nc_eui2=AeG-k9FVp5M_cs_xFXLExMe6xQmRx9yOdWT7PS3oKTwTWEQptNVxm8iKKNMykjnDFQKvCne4IbsaMbwU-FEFifFcFgcKUQWPvlgaoXG02vDCMw&_nc_oc=AQlFDd8llA_HS4zpqQTkbBiFZeY1WOC2qsTLAhd99hYA6cuZq_dIG9CJcFhCH4-mKGY&_nc_ht=scontent-hkg3-1.xx&oh=7bf8a07ac7094c29b6b2f7eabffe4f58&oe=5E1965F7), [Header overlays status bar](https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/73023618_2440548502933343_1587125028736991232_n.png?_nc_cat=100&_nc_eui2=AeEyPolfa31wQRcSaSjjk5beG7vKs_0n4k3o4xVFJWLqQY0AzvDGBv-G82uGAwpVUU6P2C_XLaQughI3y8gYfBGaF4_eqSgDI0ipWO88UJfQNA&_nc_oc=AQkMefoPATUwIepK6BnhJbuO7QZeDItZlt65Dk7j9sS1L87YDQqRAOPrRuR4qxRJzYg&_nc_ht=scontent-hkg3-1.xx&oh=fecb68b68fa9137be424be36339ea23e&oe=5E652746)

I'm using Expo SKD 35.0.0 to run this app on iPhone 6 Plus simulator (this happens to all iOS simulators).

How do I fix this? If you need more information please comment below.

My react-native-webview code:

```
<WebView
     userAgent={" "}
     style={styles.webView}
     startInLoadingState={true}
     renderLoading={() => {
           return (<ActivityIndicator/>)
           }}
     allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
     originWhitelist={['*']}
     source={{
            uri: this.state.videoLink,
            headers: {'Referer': 'https://agilearn.vn'},
}}/>
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @KęstasVenslauskas Still no luck, but you should try expo-av Video. You won't be able to use Vimeo video controller (like setting quality or volume...) but the screen won't be messed up anymore.